# Pushing a word to a stack and checking it for Palindrome

Tags: c, while-loop, stack, palindrome, getchar

Our teacher gave us homework to check for palindrome of a word using data structure "Stack".

Below is the code which I have written for the following problem: -

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdbool.h>

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    char *array;
};

void push(struct Stack stack, char a) //Push function.
{
    stack.array[++stack.top] = a; //Helps to push charater to a stack.
}

char pop(struct Stack stack) //Pop function.
{
    return stack.array[stack.top--]; //Helps to pop character from a stack.
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Stack original; //Original stack where the "Original" word will be pushed.
    original.top = -1;
    original.capacity = 10;
    original.array = calloc(original.capacity, sizeof(char));

    struct Stack checker; //Another stack that "Checks" whether the word is palindrome or not.
    checker.top = -1;
    checker.capacity = 10;
    checker.array = calloc(checker.capacity, sizeof(char));

    while(getchar()!='\0') //Getting all the characters from the stdin buffer and pushing it into "Original" stack.
    {
        push(original, getchar());
    }

    while(original.top != -1)
    {
        push(checker,pop(original)); //Popping from "Original" stack and pushing it to "Checker" stack.
    }

    while(checker.top != -1)
    {
        original.top = checker.top;
        if(original.array[original.top] != checker.array[checker.top]) //Checking every character in the stack if it is excatly same or not.
        {
            printf("It is not a palindrome.\n");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            checker.top = checker.top - 1;
        }
    }

    if(checker.top == -1)
    {
        printf("It is a palindrome.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Howsoever I am getting problem in the following line: -

```
while(getchar()!='\0') //Getting all the characters from the stdin buffer and pushing it into "Original" stack.
{
    push(original, getchar());
}
```

The following loop is running infinitely. My purpose of adding the following line is that I want to add individual characters from `stdin buffer` and `push` it in the `original` stack until it encounters `'\0'`.

What have I done wrong here? Is it illegal to do it this way?

> **Addendum: -**
>
> **Sample Input 1: -**
>   civic
>
> **Expected Output: -**
>   It is a palindrome.
>
> **Sample Input 2: -**
>   madama
>
> **Expected Output: -**
>   It is not a palindrome.

**P.S.**

The following code: -

```
while(getchar()!='\0') //Getting all the characters from the stdin buffer and pushing it into "Original" stack.
{
    push(original, getchar());
}
```

has now been replaced with: -

```
int c;
int i = 0;

while ( i < original.capacity && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
{
    push(original, c );
    ++i;
}
```

And is now working perfectly, howsoever now, for every word, my code is giving the output: -

> It is a palindrome.

Where have I applied the concept of stack incorrectly?

Comment: It's unlikely that `getchar()` reads `'\0'` from a text file. Not only that, but you throw away the character read and push the next one.

Comment: @WeatherVane `getchar()` cannot read `'\0'` from `stdin` ?

Comment: Yes it can - if there is one, but in a text file there isn't. Lines are ended by a newline.

Comment: @WeatherVane then what can be the other alternative?

Comment: `EOF` means End Of File/Input

Comment: `int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { push(original, c); }`

Comment: @WeatherVane shouldn't it be `char c`?

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla Nope. Read the documentation for the function.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla that's a beginner mistake; assuming that a character must be a `char`. I think there are almost zero (if any) library functions that involve characters which take or return the `char` type, it's usually `int`. A string is another matter though, typically an array of `char`. In this case there are 256 possible character values: but there is also `EOF` to represent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop

```
while(getchar()!='\0') //Getting all the characters from the stdin buffer and pushing it into "Original" stack.
{
    push(original, getchar());
}
```

is in any case wrong because it reads characters twice: in the condition of the loop and within the body of the loop.

And you have explicitly to enter 0 using for example keypad.

What you need is the following

```
int c;
int i = 0;

while ( i < original.capacity && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
{
    push(original, c );
    ++i;
}
```

Also there is one more problem. These functions deal with a copy of the passed arguments.

```
void push(struct Stack stack, char a) //Push function.
{
    stack.array[++stack.top] = a; //Helps to push charater to a stack.
}

char pop(struct Stack stack) //Pop function.
{
    return stack.array[stack.top--]; //Helps to pop character from a stack.
}
```

You have to declare them like

```
void push(struct Stack *stack, char a) //Push function.
{
    stack-?array[++stack->top] = a; //Helps to push charater to a stack.
}

char pop(struct Stack *stack) //Pop function.
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--]; //Helps to pop character from a stack.
}
```

That is to pass the original stack by reference through pointer.

And call these functions as for example

```
push( &original, c );
```

Otherwise the data member top will not be changed.

Here is your updated program

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    char *array;
};

void push(struct Stack *stack, char a) //Push function.
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = a; //Helps to push charater to a stack.
}

char pop(struct Stack *stack) //Pop function.
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--]; //Helps to pop character from a stack.
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Stack original; //Original stack where the "Original" word will be pushed.
    original.top = -1;
    original.capacity = 10;
    original.array = calloc(original.capacity, sizeof(char));

    struct Stack checker; //Another stack that "Checks" whether the word is palindrome or not.
    checker.top = -1;
    checker.capacity = 10;
    checker.array = calloc(checker.capacity, sizeof(char));

    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < original.capacity && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
    {
        push( &original, c );
        ++i;
    }

    while(original.top != -1)
    {
        push(&checker,pop(&original)); //Popping from "Original" stack and pushing it to "Checker" stack.
    }

    while(checker.top != -1)
    {
        original.top = checker.top;
        if(original.array[original.top] != checker.array[checker.top]) //Checking every character in the stack if it is excatly same or not.
        {
            printf("It is not a palindrome.\n");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {
            checker.top = checker.top - 1;
        }
    }

    if(checker.top == -1)
    {
        printf("It is a palindrome.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that these headers

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

are redundant.

Comment: In the above loop you mentioned, what I intend to do is that pop the last `char` of `original` stack and push it as first `char` to the `checker` stack and then compare them side by side with same index number as mentioned in `if(original.array[original.top] != checker.array[checker.top])`

Comment: Suppose the input is `1 2 3`. In `original` stack, the order of number would be `1 2 3`. whereas in the `checker` stack the order would be `3 2 1`. and then I would compare them side by side.

Comment: One more question though, won't we account for `'\0'` while pushing `char` from `stdin` to `original` and from `original` to `checker`.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla If you do not enter it explicitly using the keypad it will not present in the input buffer.

Comment: isn't `'\0'` added automatically after every word? When I use `fgets` it gets automatically added, even in `scanf`.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla No, it is not appended because you are entering single characters instead of a whole string.